# CouchDB: JavaScript Fetch API Fails To Connects Due To CORS on localhost

Tags: javascript, cors, couchdb

**After more testing, the CORS issue surfaces only when I add the `'credentials': 'include'` header. ...?**

Using Chrome browser I navigate to 127.0.0.1:5984 and get response from couchdb server.

When I call the same address using Chrome's JavaScript it fails for both http://127.0.0.1:5984 as well as http://localhost:5984.

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5984/' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

The `local.ini` file on the couchdb box has:

```
[chttpd]
enable_cors = true
[cors]
origins = *
credentials = true
methods = GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD, TRACE, PATCH
headers = accept, authorization, content-type, origin, referer, cache-control, x-requested-with, X-Couch-Id, X-Couch-Rev
```

My fetch options currently have:

```
{
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "method": "GET",
    "credentials": "include",
    "mode": "cors"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're making a CORS request which includes credentials, you cannot use `origins = *`. According to the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#access-control-allow-origin):

> Note: When responding to a credentialed requests request, the server must specify an origin in the value of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, instead of specifying the "*" wildcard.

So you need `http://localhost:5984` and any other relevant host in your `local.ini`. This issue isn't CouchDB specific, you need to explicitly specify the origins for any API to which you make a CORS request from the browser.

Comment: I think that's right. I see their documentation even says that. I think specifying the `:5984` just says "only from this port" per their [documentation](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/config/http.html#cors/origins). And, actually, port #'s seem unrelated to the be concept of origins? But that's a whole other issue. I know that js fetch (or XMLHTTPRequest) works because Fauxton works...

Comment: Yeah true, you don't need to include the port.

Comment: I got the js fetch w basic auth to couchdb working. Just send the authorization header only, and no other header, is the trick. That CORS issue sent me on a wild goose chase.